# Schema.org Comment not recognized by Google Structured Data Testing Tool

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I validated the followin `Comment` Schema.org structured data on [Google's Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) but it seems not to recognize the [`Comment` structure](https://schema.org/Comment) correctly:

**Here's my HTML (for a single comment)**

```html
<div class="comment-wrapper zoomIn animated" data-comment-id="40" data-level=
"0" data-user-id="28" id="comment-40" itemprop="comment" itemscope=
"http://schema.org/Comment">
    <div class="comment-inner">
        <div class="comment-title">
            <span class="submitted-by"><span itemprop="creator" itemscope
            itemtype="http://schema.org/Person"><span itemprop=
            "name">Jane</span></span><span class="score" title=
            "Score"><span></span>0</span> •</span>
            <meta content="2015-12-09T06:28:59Z"><time class="date-submitted"
            datetime="2015-12-09T06:28:59Z">a day ago</time> 
        </div>
        <div class="comment-content">
            <article class="comment-body">
                <p itemprop='text'>fgdfg</p>
            </article>
        </div>
        <div class="comment-options">
            <span class="upvote-num" itemprop="upvoteCount">1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="notification"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is wrong with my structure? It should recognize the `Comment` structure. It seem that it only recognizes the `Person` structured data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `itemscope="http://schema.org/Comment"`, but it should be:

```html
itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Comment"
```